# Laravel default token authentication

Tags: php, api, laravel, token

I want to use Laravel default token authentication. I was wondering should the token be refreshed at some point? Or what's the normal way of doing this?

And is the default Laravel token system safe enough. Or should I use something like OAuth?

Comment: if I understand you, you asking if Laravel is protected against CSRF? and if it is secure enough?

Comment: I guess this will answer your question in details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34422751/why-is-my-csrf-token-empty-when-using-formopen

Comment: in addition to nassim link you might look at this as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33329501/about-laravel-5-1-security/33329688#33329688